# code crashes pc and phone if window is resized

Tags: php, html, responsive-design

When I open my homepage seodevs.com it works exactly how I want it to, however, if I change the browser size on a pc or if rotating the screen on android it totally locks up the CPU of the device. I have tried in firefox, chrome, android chrome and Samsung internet. I'm sure it has something that's not quite right in the code below, but after searching and trial and error testing by removing deactivating plugins and whatnot, I have come to the conclusion that something is at amiss in the code below.

I hope someone can shed some lite on the possible issue and help my already receding hairline.

Thanks in advance.

```
<?php 

$list = get_posts($default);
do_action( 'before' ); 
$id = 'seo_reponsive_post_slider_'.rand().time();
if ( count($list) > 0 ){
?>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div id="<?php echo esc_attr( $id ) ?>" class="responsive-post-slider 
responsive-slider clearfix loading" data-lg="<?php echo esc_attr( $rows ); ?
>" data-md="<?php echo esc_attr( $rows1 ); ?>" data-sm="<?php echo esc_attr( 
$rows2 ); ?>" data-xs="<?php echo esc_attr( $rows3 ); ?>" data-mobile="<?php 
echo esc_attr( $rows4 ); ?>" data-speed="<?php echo esc_attr( $speed ); ?>" 
data-scroll="<?php echo esc_attr( $scroll ); ?>" data-interval="<?php echo 
esc_attr( $interval ); ?>" data-autoplay="<?php echo esc_attr( $autoplay ); 
?>">
<div class="resp-slider-container">
    <div class="block-title">
            <?php
            $titles = strpos($title2, ' ');
            $title = ($titles !== false) ? '<span>' . substr($title2, 0, 
$titles) . '</span>' .' '. substr($title2, $titles + 1): $title2 ;
            echo '<h3>'. $title .'</h3>';
            ?>  

        </div>
    <div class="slider responsive">
        <?php foreach ($list as $post){ ?>
            <?php if($post->post_content != $excerpt) { ?>
            <div class="item widget-pformat-detail">
                <div class="item-inner">                                
                    <div class="item-detail">
                    <h1 style="font-family:Georgia,Cambria,Times New 
 Roman,Times,serif;color:#000!important;font-weight:800;margin-
 top:1em;margin-bottom:1em;line-height:1.2;"><a href="<?php echo 
 get_permalink($post->ID)?>"><?php echo $post->post_title;?></a></h1>





 <div class="postau author media">
 <figure class="media-left">
            <img alt="" 
 src="https://s.gravatar.com/avatar/329a319f935970449afd69dd28fa4f5f?s=80" 
 srcset="https://s.gravatar.com/avatar/329a319f935970449afd69dd28fa4f5f?s=80" 
 class="avatar photo img-circle"><?php esc_html_e('', 'seodevs'); ?>
            </figure>
            <div class="media-body media-middle">
 <p>
 by Mal Tonge
 </p>
 </div>
        </div>
                        <div class="img_over">
                            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID)?>" 
>
                                <?php 
                            if ( has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ){

                                    echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 
 'seodevs_blog-responsive1' ) ? get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 
'seodevs_blog-responsive1' ): '<img 
src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/img/placeholder/'.'large'.'.png" 
alt="No thumb">';       
                            }else{
                                echo '<img src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/img/placeholder/'.'large'.'.png" alt="No thumb">';
                            }
                        ?></a>

                        </div>
                        <div class="entry-content">
                            <div class="item-title">

                                <p class="description">
                                    <?php                                       
                                        $content = 
self::ya_trim_words($post->post_excerpt, $length, '999');                       
                                        echo $content;
                                    ?>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="readmore"><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID);?>" title="View more" ><?php esc_html_e('Read more','seo_core');?><i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></a></div>

                                            <div class="entry-
 comment"style="font-size:26;color:#8dbf42;">



                <p class="entry-comments pull-cc-left">
<span class="comments-number"><?php echo $post->comment_count . ( ( $post-
>comment_count > 1 )); ?></span>
<span class="comments-text">
<h4> Comments<h4/></span>
</p>

                            <?php extract( shortcode_atts( array(
                            'show_share'            => 'true',
                            ), $atts )); {

$postTitle = get_the_title();
                                                                        echo '<div class="ts-isotope-posts-social">';
                                                                            echo '<a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/link/?url=' . get_permalink($post->ID) . '&amp;description=' . $postTitle . '" class="ts-isotope-posts-social-holder" rel="external" target="_blank"><span class="ts-isotope-posts-social-pinterest"></span></a>';
                                                                            echo '<a href="https://plusone.google.com/_/+1/confirm?hl=en&amp;url=' . get_permalink($post->ID) . '&amp;name=' . $postTitle . '" class="ts-isotope-posts-social-holder" rel="external" target="_blank"><span class="ts-isotope-posts-social-google"></span></a>';
                                                                            echo '<a href="http://twitter.com/share?text=' . $postTitle . '&url=' . get_permalink($post->ID) . '" class="ts-isotope-posts-social-holder" rel="external" target="_blank"><span class="ts-isotope-posts-social-twitter"></span></a>';
                                                                            echo '<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=' . get_permalink($post->ID) . '" class="ts-isotope-posts-social-holder" rel="external" target="_blank"><span class="ts-isotope-posts-social-facebook"></span></a>';
                                                                        echo '</div>';
                                                                    }
                                                                ?>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php } ?>
        <?php }?>
    </div>
</div>
```

It seems that it is the JS file that comes with wordpress. The resize function in the jquery.js file is causing the issue.  here is the JS that that is called but i'm useless with js.  ive tried striping out functions from this js but just cause the content not to load.  but by right clicking on the site and inspect go to the elements tab then to the event listener tab.  scroll down to resize window and click remove then the page works with no issues and resizes like a dream.

here Is the JS code.

```
var ka = /^(?:input|select|textarea)$/i,
            la = /^key/,
            ma = /^(?:mouse|pointer|contextmenu|drag|drop)|click/,
            na = /^(?:focusinfocus|focusoutblur)$/,
            oa = /^([^.]*)(?:\.(.+)|)/;

    function pa() {
            return !0
    }

    function qa() {
            return !1
    }

    function ra() {
            try {
                    return d.activeElement
            } catch(a) {}
    }

    function sa(a, b, c, d, e, f) {
            var g, h;
            if("object" == typeof b) {
                    "string" != typeof c && (d = d || c, c = void 0);
                    for(h in b) sa(a, h, c, d, b[h], f);
                    return a
            }
            if(null == d && null == e ? (e = c, d = c = void 0) : null == e && ("string" == typeof c ? (e = d, d = void 0) : (e = d, d = c, c = void 0)), e === !1) e = qa;
            else if(!e) return a;
            return 1 === f && (g = e, e = function(a) {
                    return n().off(a), g.apply(this, arguments)
            }, e.guid = g.guid || (g.guid = n.guid++)), a.each(function() {
                    n.event.add(this, b, e, d, c)
            })
    }
    n.event = {
            global: {},
            add: function(a, b, c, d, e) {
                    var f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, o, p, q, r = n._data(a);
                    if(r) {
                            c.handler && (i = c, c = i.handler, e = i.selector), c.guid || (c.guid = n.guid++), (g = r.events) || (g = r.events = {}), (k = r.handle) || (k = r.handle = function(a) {
                                    return "undefined" == typeof n || a && n.event.triggered === a.type ? void 0 : n.event.dispatch.apply(k.elem, arguments)
                            }, k.elem = a), b = (b || "").match(G) || [""], h = b.length;
                            while(h--) f = oa.exec(b[h]) || [], o = q = f[1], p = (f[2] || "").split(".").sort(), o && (j = n.event.special[o] || {}, o = (e ? j.delegateType : j.bindType) || o, j = n.event.special[o] || {}, l = n.extend({
                                    type: o,
                                    origType: q,
                                    data: d,
                                    handler: c,
                                    guid: c.guid,
                                    selector: e,
                                    needsContext: e && n.expr.match.needsContext.test(e),
                                    namespace: p.join(".")
                            }, i), (m = g[o]) || (m = g[o] = [], m.delegateCount = 0, j.setup && j.setup.call(a, d, p, k) !== !1 || (a.addEventListener ? a.addEventListener(o, k, !1) : a.attachEvent && a.attachEvent("on" + o, k))), j.add && (j.add.call(a, l), l.handler.guid || (l.handler.guid = c.guid)), e ? m.splice(m.delegateCount++, 0, l) : m.push(l), n.event.global[o] = !0);
                            a = null
                    }
            },
            remove: function(a, b, c, d, e) {
                    var f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, o, p, q, r = n.hasData(a) && n._data(a);
                    if(r && (k = r.events)) {
                            b = (b || "").match(G) || [""], j = b.length;
                            while(j--)
                                    if(h = oa.exec(b[j]) || [], o = q = h[1], p = (h[2] || "").split(".").sort(), o) {
                                            l = n.event.special[o] || {}, o = (d ? l.delegateType : l.bindType) || o, m = k[o] || [], h = h[2] && new RegExp("(^|\\.)" + p.join("\\.(?:.*\\.|)") + "(\\.|$)"), i = f = m.length;
                                            while(f--) g = m[f], !e && q !== g.origType || c && c.guid !== g.guid || h && !h.test(g.namespace) || d && d !== g.selector && ("**" !== d || !g.selector) || (m.splice(f, 1), g.selector && m.delegateCount--, l.remove && l.remove.call(a, g));
                                            i && !m.length && (l.teardown && l.teardown.call(a, p, r.handle) !== !1 || n.removeEvent(a, o, r.handle), delete k[o])
                                    } else
                                            for(o in k) n.event.remove(a, o + b[j], c, d, !0);
                            n.isEmptyObject(k) && (delete r.handle, n._removeData(a, "events"))
                    }
            },
            trigger: function(b, c, e, f) {
                    var g, h, i, j, l, m, o, p = [e || d],
                            q = k.call(b, "type") ? b.type : b,
                            r = k.call(b, "namespace") ? b.namespace.split(".") : [];
                    if(i = m = e = e || d, 3 !== e.nodeType && 8 !== e.nodeType && !na.test(q + n.event.triggered) && (q.indexOf(".") > -1 && (r = q.split("."), q = r.shift(), r.sort()), h = q.indexOf(":") < 0 && "on" + q, b = b[n.expando] ? b : new n.Event(q, "object" == typeof b && b), b.isTrigger = f ? 2 : 3, b.namespace = r.join("."), b.rnamespace = b.namespace ? new RegExp("(^|\\.)" + r.join("\\.(?:.*\\.|)") + "(\\.|$)") : null, b.result = void 0, b.target || (b.target = e), c = null == c ? [b] : n.makeArray(c, [b]), l = n.event.special[q] || {}, f || !l.trigger || l.trigger.apply(e, c) !== !1)) {
                            if(!f && !l.noBubble && !n.isWindow(e)) {
                                    for(j = l.delegateType || q, na.test(j + q) || (i = i.parentNode); i; i = i.parentNode) p.push(i), m = i;
                                    m === (e.ownerDocument || d) && p.push(m.defaultView || m.parentWindow || a)
                            }
                            o = 0;
                            while((i = p[o++]) && !b.isPropagationStopped()) b.type = o > 1 ? j : l.bindType || q, g = (n._data(i, "events") || {})[b.type] && n._data(i, "handle"), g && g.apply(i, c), g = h && i[h], g && g.apply && M(i) && (b.result = g.apply(i, c), b.result === !1 && b.preventDefault());
                            if(b.type = q, !f && !b.isDefaultPrevented() && (!l._default || l._default.apply(p.pop(), c) === !1) && M(e) && h && e[q] && !n.isWindow(e)) {
                                    m = e[h], m && (e[h] = null), n.event.triggered = q;
                                    try {
                                            e[q]()
                                    } catch(s) {}
                                    n.event.triggered = void 0, m && (e[h] = m)
                            }
                            return b.result
                    }
            },
            dispatch: function(a) {
                    a = n.event.fix(a);
                    var b, c, d, f, g, h = [],
                            i = e.call(arguments),
                            j = (n._data(this, "events") || {})[a.type] || [],
                            k = n.event.special[a.type] || {};
                    if(i[0] = a, a.delegateTarget = this, !k.preDispatch || k.preDispatch.call(this, a) !== !1) {
                            h = n.event.handlers.call(this, a, j), b = 0;
                            while((f = h[b++]) && !a.isPropagationStopped()) {
                                    a.currentTarget = f.elem, c = 0;
                                    while((g = f.handlers[c++]) && !a.isImmediatePropagationStopped()) a.rnamespace && !a.rnamespace.test(g.namespace) || (a.handleObj = g, a.data = g.data, d = ((n.event.special[g.origType] || {}).handle || g.handler).apply(f.elem, i), void 0 !== d && (a.result = d) === !1 && (a.preventDefault(), a.stopPropagation()))
                            }
                            return k.postDispatch && k.postDispatch.call(this, a), a.result
                    }
            },
            handlers: function(a, b) {
                    var c, d, e, f, g = [],
                            h = b.delegateCount,
                            i = a.target;
                    if(h && i.nodeType && ("click" !== a.type || isNaN(a.button) || a.button < 1))
                            for(; i != this; i = i.parentNode || this)
                                    if(1 === i.nodeType && (i.disabled !== !0 || "click" !== a.type)) {
                                            for(d = [], c = 0; h > c; c++) f = b[c], e = f.selector + " ", void 0 === d[e] && (d[e] = f.needsContext ? n(e, this).index(i) > -1 : n.find(e, this, null, [i]).length), d[e] && d.push(f);
                                            d.length && g.push({
                                                    elem: i,
                                                    handlers: d
                                            })
                                    }
                    return h < b.length && g.push({
                            elem: this,
                            handlers: b.slice(h)
                    }), g
            },
            fix: function(a) {
                    if(a[n.expando]) return a;
                    var b, c, e, f = a.type,
                            g = a,
                            h = this.fixHooks[f];
                    h || (this.fixHooks[f] = h = ma.test(f) ? this.mouseHooks : la.test(f) ? this.keyHooks : {}), e = h.props ? this.props.concat(h.props) : this.props, a = new n.Event(g), b = e.length;
                    while(b--) c = e[b], a[c] = g[c];
                    return a.target || (a.target = g.srcElement || d), 3 === a.target.nodeType && (a.target = a.target.parentNode), a.metaKey = !!a.metaKey, h.filter ? h.filter(a, g) : a
            },
            props: "altKey bubbles cancelable ctrlKey currentTarget detail eventPhase metaKey relatedTarget shiftKey target timeStamp view which".split(" "),
            fixHooks: {},
            keyHooks: {
                    props: "char charCode key keyCode".split(" "),
                    filter: function(a, b) {
                            return null == a.which && (a.which = null != b.charCode ? b.charCode : b.keyCode), a
                    }
            },
            mouseHooks: {
                    props: "button buttons clientX clientY fromElement offsetX offsetY pageX pageY screenX screenY toElement".split(" "),
                    filter: function(a, b) {
                            var c, e, f, g = b.button,
                                    h = b.fromElement;
                            return null == a.pageX && null != b.clientX && (e = a.target.ownerDocument || d, f = e.documentElement, c = e.body, a.pageX = b.clientX + (f && f.scrollLeft || c && c.scrollLeft || 0) - (f && f.clientLeft || c && c.clientLeft || 0), a.pageY = b.clientY + (f && f.scrollTop || c && c.scrollTop || 0) - (f && f.clientTop || c && c.clientTop || 0)), !a.relatedTarget && h && (a.relatedTarget = h === a.target ? b.toElement : h), a.which || void 0 === g || (a.which = 1 & g ? 1 : 2 & g ? 3 : 4 & g ? 2 : 0), a
                    }
            },
            special: {
                    load: {
                            noBubble: !0
                    },
                    focus: {
                            trigger: function() {
                                    if(this !== ra() && this.focus) try {
                                            return this.focus(), !1
                                    } catch(a) {}
                            },
                            delegateType: "focusin"
                    },
                    blur: {
                            trigger: function() {
                                    return this === ra() && this.blur ? (this.blur(), !1) : void 0
                            },
                            delegateType: "focusout"
                    },
                    click: {
                            trigger: function() {
                                    return n.nodeName(this, "input") && "checkbox" === this.type && this.click ? (this.click(), !1) : void 0
                            },
                            _default: function(a) {
                                    return n.nodeName(a.target, "a")
                            }
                    },
                    beforeunload: {
                            postDispatch: function(a) {
                                    void 0 !== a.result && a.originalEvent && (a.originalEvent.returnValue = a.result)
                            }
                    }
            },
            simulate: function(a, b, c) {
                    var d = n.extend(new n.Event, c, {
                            type: a,
                            isSimulated: !0
                    });
                    n.event.trigger(d, null, b), d.isDefaultPrevented() && c.preventDefault()
            }
    }, n.removeEvent = d.removeEventListener ? function(a, b, c) {
            a.removeEventListener && a.removeEventListener(b, c)
    } : function(a, b, c) {
            var d = "on" + b;
            a.detachEvent && ("undefined" == typeof a[d] && (a[d] = null), a.detachEvent(d, c))
    }, n.Event = function(a, b) {
            return this instanceof n.Event ? (a && a.type ? (this.originalEvent = a, this.type = a.type, this.isDefaultPrevented = a.defaultPrevented || void 0 === a.defaultPrevented && a.returnValue === !1 ? pa : qa) : this.type = a, b && n.extend(this, b), this.timeStamp = a && a.timeStamp || n.now(), void(this[n.expando] = !0)) : new n.Event(a, b)
    }, n.Event.prototype = {
            constructor: n.Event,
            isDefaultPrevented: qa,
            isPropagationStopped: qa,
            isImmediatePropagationStopped: qa,
            preventDefault: function() {
                    var a = this.originalEvent;
                    this.isDefaultPrevented = pa, a && (a.preventDefault ? a.preventDefault() : a.returnValue = !1)
            },
            stopPropagation: function() {
                    var a = this.originalEvent;
                    this.isPropagationStopped = pa, a && !this.isSimulated && (a.stopPropagation && a.stopPropagation(), a.cancelBubble = !0)
            },
            stopImmediatePropagation: function() {
                    var a = this.originalEvent;
                    this.isImmediatePropagationStopped = pa, a && a.stopImmediatePropagation && a.stopImmediatePropagation(), this.stopPropagation()
            }
    }, n.each({
            mouseenter: "mouseover",
            mouseleave: "mouseout",
            pointerenter: "pointerover",
            pointerleave: "pointerout"
    }, function(a, b) {
            n.event.special[a] = {
                    delegateType: b,
                    bindType: b,
                    handle: function(a) {
                            var c, d = this,
                                    e = a.relatedTarget,
                                    f = a.handleObj;
                            return e && (e === d || n.contains(d, e)) || (a.type = f.origType, c = f.handler.apply(this, arguments), a.type = b), c
                    }
            }
    }), l.submit || (n.event.special.submit = {
            setup: function() {
                    return n.nodeName(this, "form") ? !1 : void n.event.add(this, "click._submit keypress._submit", function(a) {
                            var b = a.target,
                                    c = n.nodeName(b, "input") || n.nodeName(b, "button") ? n.prop(b, "form") : void 0;
                            c && !n._data(c, "submit") && (n.event.add(c, "submit._submit", function(a) {
                                    a._submitBubble = !0
                            }), n._data(c, "submit", !0))
                    })
            },
            postDispatch: function(a) {
                    a._submitBubble && (delete a._submitBubble, this.parentNode && !a.isTrigger && n.event.simulate("submit", this.parentNode, a))
            },
            teardown: function() {
                    return n.nodeName(this, "form") ? !1 : void n.event.remove(this, "._submit")
            }
    }), l.change || (n.event.special.change = {
            setup: function() {
                    return ka.test(this.nodeName) ? ("checkbox" !== this.type && "radio" !== this.type || (n.event.add(this, "propertychange._change", function(a) {
                            "checked" === a.originalEvent.propertyName && (this._justChanged = !0)
                    }), n.event.add(this, "click._change", function(a) {
                            this._justChanged && !a.isTrigger && (this._justChanged = !1), n.event.simulate("change", this, a)
                    })), !1) : void n.event.add(this, "beforeactivate._change", function(a) {
                            var b = a.target;
                            ka.test(b.nodeName) && !n._data(b, "change") && (n.event.add(b, "change._change", function(a) {
                                    !this.parentNode || a.isSimulated || a.isTrigger || n.event.simulate("change", this.parentNode, a)
                            }), n._data(b, "change", !0))
                    })
            },
            handle: function(a) {
                    var b = a.target;
                    return this !== b || a.isSimulated || a.isTrigger || "radio" !== b.type && "checkbox" !== b.type ? a.handleObj.handler.apply(this, arguments) : void 0
            },
            teardown: function() {
                    return n.event.remove(this, "._change"), !ka.test(this.nodeName)
            }
    }), l.focusin || n.each({
            focus: "focusin",
            blur: "focusout"
    }, function(a, b) {
            var c = function(a) {
                    n.event.simulate(b, a.target, n.event.fix(a))
            };
            n.event.special[b] = {
                    setup: function() {
                            var d = this.ownerDocument || this,
                                    e = n._data(d, b);
                            e || d.addEventListener(a, c, !0), n._data(d, b, (e || 0) + 1)
                    },
                    teardown: function() {
                            var d = this.ownerDocument || this,
                                    e = n._data(d, b) - 1;
                            e ? n._data(d, b, e) : (d.removeEventListener(a, c, !0), n._removeData(d, b))
                    }
            }
    }), n.fn.extend({
            on: function(a, b, c, d) {
                    return sa(this, a, b, c, d)
            },
            one: function(a, b, c, d) {
                    return sa(this, a, b, c, d, 1)
            },
            off: function(a, b, c) {
                    var d, e;
                    if(a && a.preventDefault && a.handleObj) return d = a.handleObj, n(a.delegateTarget).off(d.namespace ? d.origType + "." + d.namespace : d.origType, d.selector, d.handler), this;
                    if("object" == typeof a) {
                            for(e in a) this.off(e, b, a[e]);
                            return this
                    }
                    return b !== !1 && "function" != typeof b || (c = b, b = void 0), c === !1 && (c = qa), this.each(function() {
                            n.event.remove(this, a, c, b)
                    })
            },
            trigger: function(a, b) {
                    return this.each(function() {
                            n.event.trigger(a, b, this)
                    })
            },
            triggerHandler: function(a, b) {
                    var c = this[0];
                    return c ? n.event.trigger(a, b, c, !0) : void 0
            }
```

Comment: If your problem happens when resizing the window then it must caused by some JavaScript code that runs attached to the [onresize event](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onresize.asp), you should update the question with the final HTML/JS code, since the PHP code is not relevant for this problem.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply Alberto,  I have edited the question to include the HTML output. code for this specific element. hope this helps in determining the problem.  I've been working on this for 2 days now but coding is not my specialty.  I'm hoping to the experienced eyes this would stand out a mile. but obviously not.  Thanks again for your help

Comment: Ok i fixed the issue now, The error was from a duplicate within the jquary.js file that come with wordpress. duplicate was g = r.events = {} once removing one of them everything is working fine.  I will report this issue to wordpress as this is a wordpress file.

Comment: @SEODEVS Hi I'm having a jQuery issue and I noticed the same duplicate when debugging through Chrome Dev tools. Do you know where I can find the jquery.js file that comes with wordpres?